# Using .list() in Grails with other query options

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I would like to use the `.list` call with another query (for example a date range or all of a certain type). Is this possible or do I need to build a custom `.find` call wrapping all the options in `.list` like offset and max?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to look at the [Dynamic Finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) and/or [Where Queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) sections of the Grails doc.  If you want to give a more specific example of what you're trying to accomplish I can better answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
filter = { it.datePublished >= 'date1' && it.datePublished <= 'date2' }
def filteredList = Book.list(max: 10, offset: 100).collect(filter)
```